# publish-for-arch issues in meteor

Tags: meteor, atmosphere

I've created package and published it, It is just a simple wrapper of "phantom"

I deployed it using

```
sudo meteor publih --create
```

then added it to my app

```
$> meteor show sasi513:phantom@1.0.0
Version 1.0.0 : phantom node Package wrapper
      Architectures: os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova


Maintained by sasi513.
```

**EDIT**
Then when I try to deploy it `meteor deploy xxx.meteor.com`

```
Errors prevented deploying:
While building the application:
error: Unable to download package builds for this architecture.
```

and I tried to publish-for-arch

```
sudo meteor publish-for-arch sasi513:phantom@1.0.0
sasi513:phantom: updating npm dependencies -- phantom...
Bundling build...
Creating package build...
Uploading build...
Publishing package build...
Error from package server
: Cannot override existing build [403]
```

What is wrong here?Anyone has idea about this

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: I published it from linux_64 bit and it is published, It was deployed and It  shows no errors and nothing is showing in the servers, not even errors in the console

Comment: Oh I see. I don't know, maybe you can deploy it to your own server and look at the machine and see what it is actually doing. Like I said phantom.js is pretty crazy.

Comment: I tried to deploy to my own servers, but getting error ` info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/opt/meteor/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/sasi513:phantom/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode/node_modules/weak',` , anyway thanks for your help it helps me to publish-for-arch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says:

> You need to run publish-for-arch from a different architecture to
>   upload a different build.

Are you running the command on a different architecture? Or the same machine? Because running the command on the same machine wont work.[1] Based on your description, it sounds like you didn't try it from the other architecture you want to support.

[1] http://docs.meteor.com/#meteorpublishforarch

Comment: I want to deploy to meteor servers, from which architecture it needs to run this command?

Comment: I published it from ubuntu, Meteor servers need which arch?

Comment: Probably linux 64bit, but I don't know, did you try it with just your ubuntu build? Did it break when you tried to use your package on a meteor server? Publishing to atmosphere is not deploying to a meteor server, it simply makes your package available to other users.

Comment: As in my question, I'm not able to deploy it to servers

Comment: `meteor deploy` deploys an app to meteor's servers. `meteor publish` publishes a package to atmosphere. A package is a library others can download for use in their own apps. A package is not an app, it's like a library. Apps use packages. You cannot deploy packages without them being in an app. Atmosphere is a package repository.

Comment: I got that error, when I tried to deploy it to `meteor deploy xxx.meteor.com`

Comment: Ohh ok, what do you see when you type `$ uname -a` on the command line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62447/discussion-between-iamme-and-bjorn-tipling).